# How to Import files from media library into database with Links

Tags: wordpress, import, media

I installed a plugin for translation on a Wordpress installation. All image files were automatically doubled (one image for both languages). But I don't need that at all.

So I deleted everything from the media library and then read all the images from the server back into the database using the “Media Sync” plugin.

The only problem is that all the files appear there again, but without any links to the pages on which the images are to be used. As a result, the images on the pages are not displayed.

How can I export the data for just the images from the old database (from before the plugin was used) and import it into the new database?

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag, since this isn't really related to the SQL _language_. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're using.